# How can I bind to global clipboard events in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, clipboard, clipboard-interaction

I need to make a simple service application that will bind to the Windows clipboard.  Specifically, any time a copy/cut operation takes place I want to analyze the content and under certain conditions do something with the data.

I know that clipboard managers exist but, from what I gather, they use old COM APIs.

I'm not afraid of COM dll calls but I'm curious, is there a way to do this in pure .Net or do I still need to register a clipboard listener using COM?

Comment: Is this in Windows 7 or 8 ?

Comment: As a side note, this article (http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3359891/C-Tip-Monitoring-Clipboard-Activity-in-C.htm) is what every implementation does to listen to the clipboard.  As you can see from the article, it is dated from 2004.  I can use this as a solution, but in the days of Windows 8, I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: @MicahArmantrout.  Assume both.

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333746/clipboardinterop-content-changed-fires-twice

Comment: @MicahArmantrout That's essentially what I'm trying to avoid.  I don't mind doing it that way.  Especially if that's the "correct" way to do it.  However, I'd rather avoid com/interop calls if this has completely implemented in a .net assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then this is all new I can see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205867.aspx#events

and I think this is strictly Windows 8

Comment: I see.  I'm having to read between the lines a bit, but I do think this solves the problem.  It looks like there is a way to do this with the forward-moving way of publishing apps through the Windows App Store.  I imagine for legacy apps, I most still use COM.  For newer, Win 8 Apps, can use the method outlined above.  Not what I was hoping for, but certainly an answer.